# Adding strings from range into an array

Tags: excel, vba

Now this could sound very silly as it looks very simple but I am not able to understand the way how to declare a single dimension array that can take strings from a range as values. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
Sub myArr()
Dim V(1 To 2) As String
V(1) = "Hello"
V(2) = "World"
'V = Range("A1:A2").Value 'What is wrong in this syntax?
End Sub
```

I have two strings "Hello" & "World" in range A1:A2. I searched for it and saw some articles where loops were written to get all the string values in the range into an array of string type. How can I get this into an array in a single line syntax. Is there a way to do it? Please help.

**EDIT** : for better explanation

I am looking for a 1D array and wanted to check if there is a **single line code** that can put range values in the array which should be of type string without having to loop its elements. I have updated my question. Kindly have a look at it.

If I loop through the elements, I would get something like this
[image]

But I am looking for string type values like below with a one liner code
[image]

Comment: `Range("A1:A2").Value` will return a 2 dimensional array. What are you looking for ?

Comment: The simplest way looks to be `Dim v`, then `V = Range("A1:A2").Value` will return a 2D array and you can use its elements as `Debug.print V(1,1), V(2, 1)`. Is it a need to be 1D?

Comment: And the syntax is bad only against the array declaration... It should be declared as `Variant`. As I tried showing in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes. it needs to be 1D. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the range is a column then use `Transpose`, providing there  less than 65,537 rows.

```vb
Sub myArr()
    Dim V As Variant, i As Long
    V = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A2").Value)
    For i = LBound(V) To UBound(V)
        Debug.Print i, V(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i was looking for a one-line. I have updated my question for better understanding of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: `V = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A2").Value)` is one line and V is a ID array.

Comment: I tried this already. if you look at the VBE Locals windows and the screenshot I provided on top, it shows type is Variant/String. I wanted only string. I just now got my answer with this one line where the type shows String `V = Filter(Application.Index(Range("A1:A2").Value, [{1,2}]), False, False)` but the problem here is, I cannot keep on adding `{1,2,3,4,5}` for a larger data.

Comment: @kawal `V = Filter(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A10").Value), "")`